# How can I load a function, which can add global variables, without using exec(open(...))?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a SymPy python project which is working well but I currently need to use `exec(open(...))` at the start of each file. I would like to know if I can avoid this? Partly because I've read that `exec` should be avoided buy I would also just like to discover any possible alternatives to my current approach.

The following is a heavily simplified version of what I have. There is a file `hat.py` with a function, which expects a symbol as an input and returns a new symbol with the suffix 'h' added. Importantly it also adds this new symbol to the global namespace.

```py
from sympy import Symbol

def hat(var):
    nameh = str(var)+"h"
    globals()[nameh] = Symbol(nameh)
    return globals()[nameh]
```

My project involves multiple files which want to use the `hat()` function as follows.

```py
from sympy import Symbol

exec(open("hat.py").read()) 

x = Symbol('x')
e1 = x + hat(x)
print(xh + e1)
```

If `hat()` instead came from an `import` statement, `xh` would not be defined here and would return an error. I would need to use `import` after every use of `hat` to add the new variables to the namespace. This is not an option, as I have hundreds of symbols and hundreds of uses of `hat`. I also don't want to just import thousands of symbols preemptively.

Is there any other way I can load functions with the ability to dynamically add variables to the top-level namespace?

Comment: Why are you using `exec(open(...))` instead of `import hat`?

Comment: You can add an argument to your hat functions and pass the namespace you want to add those variables. Then in the function you call the namespace instead of globals(). However this is still a weird way of doing things

Comment: With `import hat` it can't add variables to the top-level `globals()`, in this example `xh` wouldn't be defined

Comment: I've tried passing the namespace, how does that work? Can I just pass it globals() and it will be able to change variables in it even though it doesn't have access to the top-level namespace?

Comment: Yeah i just tried it, it works, but it's still weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, inspired by kubatucka's suggestion. One can point a module variable to the global namespace. This gives me all the functionality I had, by replacing an `exec()` line with an `import` line and set `globals()` namespace line.

function file hat.py:

```py
from sympy import Symbol

def set_global_namespacece(namespace):
    global global_namespace
    global_namespace = namespace
    
def hat(var):
    nameh = str(var)+"h"
    global_namespace[nameh] = Symbol(nameh)
    return global_namespace[nameh]
```

project file x_eqns.py:

```py
from sympy import Symbol

from hat import *
set_global_namespacece(globals())

x = Symbol('x')
e1 = x + hat(x)
print(xh + e1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question but I don't think its a good way to code:

```
from sympy import Symbol

def hat(var,namespace):
    nameh = str(var)+"h"
    namespace[nameh] = Symbol(nameh)
    return namespace[nameh]
```

Then in the project:

```
from sympy import Symbol
from hat import hat


x = Symbol('x')
e1 = x + hat(x,globals())
print(xh + e1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that could work, however I would have to add a wrapper for `hat()` at the top of each file so I don't need to pass `global()` each time. Furthermore, I didn't say in my post but I also have similar functions `tilde()` and `bar()` which would need wrappers

Comment: You could also consider other ways of getting xh. You could subclass simpy Symbol and code methods for creating and getting xh as x.h, xtilde as x.tilde etc. Or put them in a dictionnary.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've considered those options. Both the variables and symbols being simple phrases 'xhh' 'xt' and 'hx' etc. keeps the code concise, readable and I can print equations and instantly use any of the variables in later lines of code

Comment: This inspired a helpful answer posted below, thanks for your help